# Query Search FB with postman

Tags: facebook, postman

i'm trying fb query search on postman

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pages/search?q=Facebook
  &fields=id,name,location,link
  &access_token={access-token}
```

and it returns this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Page Public Metadata Access requires either app secret proof or an app token",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "A0DGbr5CxQEimI0NDK9UyZj"
    }
}
```

how do i fix this error? i'm new at consuming social media API, and i've got standard apps on developers.faceboook.com

Comment: Please check your token in [Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/). The error message states, that your token is missing "Page Public Metadata Access". You need this permission for accessing page data.

Comment: Type User
Metadata {"auth_type":"rerequest"}

this is what i got, what should i do? @MichaelHirschler

Comment: Looks like you've got a user token, you need a page token, take a look at [Get a Page Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#get-a-page-access-token)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference#page-public-metadata-access

Comment: okay, i'll come back here after i learn it

thank you in advanced